# Looking for Resources/Topics for QFT Math Background

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

I made the mistake of purchasing *Toward the Mathematics of Quantum Field Theory* by Paugam, the problem being I have more of a background in physics/engineering than in mathematics. Despite my error, I'd like to read it anyway, though I find myself lacking the prerequisite knowledge. I have a rudimentary understanding of variational calculus and differential forms, but clearly something more is required.

Hence, if you have read the book or know of its contents, could you suggest a list of topics and/or resources to gain the necessary mathematical background?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27700/quantum-field-theory-from-a-mathematical-point-of-view This might help you

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that looks like the opposite situation to my own, unfortunately